# iOS on test device update from iOS 7 to 8 and NOT 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have an iPhone 4s that runs iOS7. Is there a way to update to iOS8 and NOT 9?

I have tried to download iOS 8.4.1 ipsw file and do manual restore with no luck (also in DFU mode).

Anybody knows a method? Want to test on iOS 8 on a real device.

[image: Error]

Comment: What does clicking More Information tell you?

Comment: @matt standard stuff that I have checked. Have always been able to update, so I think that 8.4.1 is not signed by apple anymore, but I thought there must be a way for their developers to install specific version for testing. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201442

Comment: You know that there is a different ipsw file for every iPhone model, right? Where did you find iOS 8.4.1 to download for the iPhone 4s?

Comment: @matt of course amigo I have done this for a long time :) Found it on the internet specific for this model. Have tried different files same result. Has to do with apple not signing the version, but there must be another way.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try asking this on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rmaddy i tend to disagree since it has everything to do with programming since this is not a general public question. This is very relevant for testing so it is very relevant to programming.

Comment: No, it's not a programming question. It's a question about how to install software on a piece of hardware. The fact that you plan to use the hardware to test an app you are writing is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days you could save your shsh files (i guess it is the signature that you get from apple during restore), and then you could use it for restoring the os that wasn't signed by Apple anymore. I don't know if this still works. You can read more about it here: http://www.saurik.com/id/12. However, if you never saved your shsh then i think there is no chance of installing iOS 8 anymore.

Comment: yeah i did play with shsh files with TinyUmbrella back in the days but haven't the ones for iOS8. Damn!